# Can Technical support have remote access to my computer?

Tags: access-control, remote

I was having problems with my computer which has windows 10. So I contacted with a live agent of Microsoft and followed some procedures and gave him remote access to my computer. While working, my internet dropped and I was disconnected.

He had created a local account on my pc. Named it "test" and gave it Administration access.

My question is: Can that agent take remote access again without my permission? Can he see my private info and password?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about your computer are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [security.se] or [su].